# Find all the ways to choose $k$ objects from a list of $n$ objects (using a graph?)

Tags: algorithms, graphs, combinatorics

I was playing around with graph theory and I noticed that a directed integer graph with unique vertices $V$ and edges $E$ such that each vertex only points to vertices with a higher value can be used to enumerate all $n \choose 2$ ways to choose $2$ values from a total of $\left|V\right|$ possible values.

For example:

[image]

Here, $V = \left\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \right\}$ and $E = \left\{ (0,1),(0,2),\cdots,(5,6) \right\}$ and creating the initial graph is of the order $O(n^2)$. $E$ readily contains all possible pairs of numbers chosen from the list.

I was wondering if the same strategy could be used to enumerate any $n \choose k$ where $0 \leq k \leq n$, or if there are more efficient algorithms for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generalize your approach to $k$-subsets of an $n$-set, you would need to build a hypergraph. Ordinary graph edges are relations between *pairs* of vertices. Hypergraphs allow relations between arbitrary sets of vertices. They are *extremely* general objects, essentially representing families of sets.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35867033) provides two good answers for how to (reasonably) efficiently enumerate these subsets. The first uses bit magic and is a special case when $n$ is small enough. The second takes a recursive approach which saves having to compute the first $k-1$ elements of a $k$ subset multiple times, but only really helps if enumerating over several consecutive values of $k$.